# We have a user inputting a date in m/d/Y and i'm trying to get it into Y/m/d to save into MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, yii2

we're having a user input a date in m/d/Y in the glyphicon-calender, we're trying to get it into Y/m/d for MYSQL like this, but it won't validate or save.

```
 // Normalize datetime input
        if (!empty($this->requested_ship_date)) {
            $date = new \DateTime($this->requested_ship_date);
            $this->requested_ship_date = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        }
```

we're getting a database exception that says transaction is inactive with the error coming from this line in our controller

```
 if (Yii::$app->request->post() && $model->validate() && $model->save())
```

here is the input code,

```
 <?= $form->field($model->order, 'requested_ship_date', [
     'inputTemplate' =>
         '<div class="input-group date"><span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>{input}</div>',
                        ])->textInput([
                            'value' => (isset($model->order->requested_ship_date)) ? Yii::$app->formatter->asDate($model->order->requested_ship_date) : '',
                        ]) ?>
```

Comment: Is `$model->save()` an `ActiveRecord::save()` method or is it overriden?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **createFromFormat** method from **DateTime** class.

```
// Normalize datetime input
if (!empty($this->requested_ship_date)) {
    $newDateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $this->requested_ship_date);
    $this->requested_ship_date = $newDateTime->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

Use the format as you need it.

Comment: still getting the same database exception error, Failed to commit transaction: transaction was inactive.

Comment: it's not generating a SQL code because its failing the validation on the model, would beforeValidate() be appropriate to use and if so where?

Comment: looking through the debugger log, it does convert to the correct format for SQL, but then the model fails due to a validation error

Comment: Pls. check the validation rule, what is it seeking?

Comment: ```$return[] = [['requested_ship_date'], 'date'];```